# How to achieve long polling with multiple servers

Tags: rest, microservices, long-polling, service-discovery

We have a service that runs on multiple servers. Clients connect to any of these servers to wait for some event. The connection between the client and server is long-polling style. Meaning the server will not respond, until there is event happening. The client will keep the connection open.

For example, we have servers: s1, s2, s3. We have client c1, which is connecting to s3 currently.

Now the problem is the event may be triggered on different servers. For example, someone connects to s1 and triggers some event. If that event is related to c1, how can s1 tell s3 that the event is ready and it should respond to c1 immediately?

Comment: This sounds like a great use-case for a message queue. Have you considered this? There are a number of good message queue providers, including ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Redis (not strictly a MQ), and many others (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue#See_also).

Comment: Good advice. So each server needs subscribe to the same topic and process messages even not related to current server? That looks like a big waste.

Comment: @jiaguo,  yes that is waste,  on top of that,  we need to define every instance of that service as individual 'consumer group' (in kafka terms).   Looks like it will be maintaince issue.